# AppDelegate error after upgrading to Cocos2d 2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, appdelegate

In an attempt to fix issues with iOS 6 and the iphone 5 I have upgraded the game I'm developing from cocos2d 1.1 to cocos2d 2.1.  After going through and changing out all the code I'm now getting this error:

'Unable to instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named AppDelegate is loaded.'

AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m are definitely included in my project.  I do note that they define the class AppController rather than AppDelegate - but that's how it is in the cocos2d 2.1 test project that compiles and runs fine.  The code I've got in AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m are copied directly from the empty test project, with the exception that I've added Flurry.h and the line to include Flurry analytics in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cocos2D 1.0

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//app.viewController.view
```

Cocos2D 2.0

```
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//app.navController.view
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure where the lines of code you're talking about are but it pointed me to the solution which was to replace this line in main.m -     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
with this:     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
Thanks!